# Return JSON object from php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am making an AJAX `GET` request using jQuery to a PHP file. I want the PHP script to return a JSON object, however, currently it is returning a JSON string. I realise I can use `JSON.parse` in the jQuery code, however, any experience I have in making an AJAX call to an API a JSON object is returned. I am trying to do the same with the php script however, it is returning a string as opposed to an object.

Does anyone know what the best practice is here, and if the best practise is to return a JSON object how I would do this using PHP?

Please see the code below:

**js**

```
$.get('test.php', function(data){
    console.log((data));
});
```

**php**

```
<?php

$jsonAnswer = array('test' => 'true');
echo json_encode($jsonAnswer);
```

Comment: What's the problem with `JSON.parse`? There's probably some jQuery method that parses the response automatically, which might be what you're thinking about.

Comment: its not that there is a problem with `JSON.parse` but i just want to know if i can do this server side so that the correct format is received in the browser. does this make sense?

Comment: You can only send strings over the internet.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @gcampbell i could be wrong but i don't think that this is true.

Comment: Try using tcpdump. It gives you strings. Anyway, you'd have to convert the PHP associative array to a JavaScript object.

Comment: @gcampbell thanks, but answers below are what I am looking for

Comment: That's because jQuery calls `JSON.parse` for you. Anyway, it works now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your PHP file, change the content type to `application/json`.

**JS**

```
$.get('/process.php', function(data) {      
    console.log(data);
} );
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

    header( "Content-type: application/json" );

    $jsonAnswer = array('test' => 'true');
    echo json_encode($jsonAnswer);
```

Then your console should read `Object {test: "true"}` rather than just the JSON string.

Comment: this is what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Add json to the end of your get function to return json

```
$.get('test.php', function(data){
    console.log((data));
},'json');//here
```

and/or add this header in php

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

more info [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)

Comment: get, getjson, ajax same thing

Comment: @madalinivascu no not same thing.

Comment: this is what I was looking for, however, i didn't have to add `'json`' to the get request

Comment: the json at the end ensures that the data received is parsed as json

Comment: @madalinivascu jQuery tries to automatically guess it.

Comment: $.get and $.getjson both send GET requests to the server only. You can not send data in any other way using these methods.  $.ajax is used to send any type of request to the server: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, and DELETE.  It is the most dynamic, and in my humble opinion, the best method to use for data requests, if you're using the jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying PHP script you can do:

```
$.get( "test.php", function( data ) {
 var arr = $.parseJSON(data);
 console.log(arr);
 alert(arr.test);
});
```

Comment: Although technically you can just parse the json (you can use JSON.parse() which is native to JavaScript instead of going through the jQuery library to do so), sending text based responses that are meant to be JSON responses is not a good idea and can lead to mismatching data and unexpected results. -1.