# Validate form data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, jquery-validate

I have a form that that is already validated by jquery.validate.min.js, what I want is another validation method, ajax call to mysql to check if the email address is already in my DB. How do I merge the validations? I already played a little with the codes but can't figure it out.

My form: http://demos.creative-tim.com/wizard-demo-register?_ga=2.138099576.979789193.1518540669-1813170823.1518540669

My validation code:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
  var email_state = false;
  $('#email').on('blur', function() {
    var email = $('#email').val();
    if (email == '') {
      email_state = false;
      return;
    }
    $.ajax({
      url: 'index.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {
        'email_check': 1,
        'email': email,
      },
      success: function(response) {
        if (response == 'taken') {
          email_state = false;
          alert('email is taken');
        } else if (response == 'not_taken') {
          email_state = true;
          alert('email available');
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The PHP who process the email check:

```
        <?php
      $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'subscribers');
      if (isset($_POST['email_check'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM subscribers WHERE email='$email'";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {
          echo "taken";
        }else{
          echo 'not_taken';
        }
        exit();
      }
      ?>
```

Comment: It can be done on your server, returning a response, do you have that implemented already?

Comment: Yes i do, i already tried doing it myself but i don't know exactly where the function should be placed. Sometimes the Next button just stops responding or the JS breaks..

Comment: Or how can i do it more simply, without needing to merge the scripts?

Comment: Are you using express? or which framework are you using?

Comment: Oh I see, you're using a php server, can you add your api endpoint code in your question so I can take a look?

Comment: Don't know how to create one, but i can give you access to a server where the files are hosted

Comment: Actually, the files can be downloaded for free https://www.creative-tim.com/product/bootstrap-wizard#  , i already have the php file which processes the data and sends a response to the javascript

Comment: Ok, could you add the php code as well in your question? Need to see where the data are coming from.

Comment: Done. I already tested the codes on a simple form and data is validated.

Comment: So you solved it?

Comment: No, uploaded the php code..but don't know how will help you..thx for support

Comment: Ok, so what are u getting via ajax? you can do a `console.log(response)` to check it

Comment: Actually, it works, don't know what i did wrong last time..by any chance do you know how to disable/enable the submit button in a nice way until the email is valid?

Comment: Take a look at my answer.

Comment: You should have performed a search before posting this question.  See:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/16577120/594235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [json_encode](http://nz.php.net/json_encode) what you need to do is return a response (ex: true or false) to javascript from php ([check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38243884/1473423)) .

Then check in the success js function the response, if it is true, then the email is already in the database, and alert the user, otherwise, submit the form with the email value.

There are two ways to accomplish this, 1) Make an ajax request for every keystroke on the email field `$('#email-input').on('keyup')`and once the response is false, enable the submit button via jquery `$('#submit-button').prop('disabled', false)` note that in your button html tag you should have the disabled property by default `<input type="submit" id="submit-button" value="Submit" disabled />` and after the validation occurs you disable it, then it's going to be clickable and the user will be able to submit the form.

The problem is, that you're going to make a lot of ajax calls when the user types in the email address, and you don't want that, instead what you can do is to just make the request when the user submit the form (click on the submit button) and then prevent the default behaviour (sending a post request via form) for you to check via ajax if the email is already in use or not, if it is, do not submit the form and display a message, otherwise, submit the form.

`<form id="form" action="http://foo.com" method="post">...</form>`

```
$('#form').on('submit', function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault() // prevent default behaviour (making a post request)
  // do your ajax call here to check the email availability
  // if it's taken, do nothing and just display a message to the user
  // otherwise, submit the form: $(this).submit()
})
```

Cheers.

Comment: Actually is not a submit button, i added an id tag to it so it can process the data....ev.preventDefault(); will do it? Also, the form stops at the end of the process. Creating multiple forms will not break my code?

Comment: Also... i can do action="#" , this way i don't need to modify the code? Thx

Comment: If there's not `<input type="submit" /> ` then there's no need to use `ev.preventDefault()` so after you process the data just submit the form via jquery `$('#form').submit()`, how is the form stopping at the end of the process?

Comment: Actually it should look like this $("#submit").prop("disabled", null);

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so fast...A+